# Issue with mixed C++ and Fortran code

Tags: c++, fortran

I am having a strange problem with my Fortran program. Here are some details about my application:

- Uses `ALLOCATABLE` Data structures to hold information
- Interfaces with a C++ dll which returns a pointer to an array of doubles. I convert the C++ array pointer to Fortran pointer using the intrinsic method `c_f_pointer`
- Reads from an XML file and writes outputs to an XML file, and two text files.

I am using `gfortran` to compile Fortran and the *Simply Fortran* IDE. On the C++ side, I am using `gcc` and *code::Blocks*. The application builds without any problem and runs under debug mode.

However, when I double click the application executable to see what such a launch would do, it was not responding. I had to go to Task Manager and kill the program. I tried multiple times and every time that happened. I deleted the output files created by the application & gmon.out, then double clicked the executable and voila, the program runs again.

It might run a few times and randomly it will freeze. Then I repeat the above process and sometimes that would bring the application back to life. I am really lost what is the problem here. Is it a process of bad memory management? Is it something to do with how the C++ pointer and Fortran pointer is handled?

I thought it could be a problem with the debug version, so I changed the project to options to no include debug variables, but the problem persists.

I can try to make a simple program which demonstrates the issue if it is needed.

Any ideas/help/suggestion is much appreciated.

*New Information

I tried creating a small working example as asked in the comments and while doing that I solved the issue. However I do not know the reason it solved. So to understand it better I put my CPP header and the source file here:

*DLL.h*

```
#ifndef DLL_H_INCLUDED
#define DLL_H_INCLUDED

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else

#endif

extern "C"
{

double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl *Function1(int InputCombination, double Input1, double Input2, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function2(double DBTemperature, double WBTemperature, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function3(double DBTemperature, double WBTemperature, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function4(double DBTemperature, double WBTemperature, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function5(double DBTemperature, double WBTemperature, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function6(double DBTemperature, double WBTemperature, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function7(double DBTemperature, double WBTemperature, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function8(double DBTemperature, double RelHumidity, double Pressure,int LoadLibraryFlag=1);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function9(double DBTemperature, double HumRatio, double Pressure);
double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function10(double DBTemperature, double Enthalpy, double Pressure);

}

double DB,WB,HR,RH,DP,SpVOL,ENTH;
const double CtoK = 273.15;
const double KtoC = -273.15;

#endif // DLL_H_INCLUDED
```

*DLL.cpp*

```
#include "DLL.h"

typedef double (__cdecl *fp_BisectionRootFinderTYPE) (double, double, double, double, double*, int, double(*)(double,double*));

extern fp_BisectionRootFinderTYPE BisectionRootFinder;

fp_BisectionRootFinderTYPE BisectionRootFinder;

double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl *CalcAirProperties(int InputCombination, double Input1, double Input2, double Pressure)
{
/*
 Input Combination:
    1: Given DB [C], WB [C] and Pressure [kPa]
    2: Given DB [C], RH and Pressure [kPa]
    3: Given DB [C], phi and Pressure [kPa]
    4: Given DB [C], DP [C] and Pressure [kPa]
*/

    double *AirProperties = new double[7];
/*
  Air Properties:
    [0]: Dry bulb Temperature [C]
    [1]: Wet bulb temperature [C]
    [2]: Humidity ratio []
    [3]: Relative Humidity []
    [4]: Dew point Temperature [C]
    [5]: Specific Volume [m3/kg_da]
    [6]: Enthalpy [kJ/kg_da]
*/

    HINSTANCE MathRoutinesInstance;

    MathRoutinesInstance = LoadLibrary("./MathRoutines.dll");

    BisectionRootFinder = (fp_BisectionRootFinderTYPE) GetProcAddress(MathRoutinesInstance,"BisectionRootFinder");

    if(InputCombination == 1)
    {
      DB = Input1;
      WB = Input2;
      HR = Function2(DB,WB,Pressure);
      RH = Function3(DB,WB,Pressure);
      DP = Function4(DB,WB,Pressure);
      SpVOL = Function5(DB,WB,Pressure);
      ENTH = Function6(DB,WB,Pressure);
    }
    else if(InputCombination == 2)
    {
      DB = Input1;
      RH = Input2;
      WB = Function8(DB,RH,Pressure,1);
      HR = Function2(DB,WB,Pressure);
      DP = Function4(DB,WB,Pressure);
      SpVOL = Function5(DB,WB,Pressure);
      ENTH = Function6(DB,WB,Pressure);
    }
    else if(InputCombination == 3)
    {
      DB = Input1;
      HR = Input2;
      RH = Function7(DB,HR,Pressure);
      WB = Function8(DB,RH,Pressure,1);
      DP = Function4(DB,WB,Pressure);
      SpVOL = Function5(DB,WB,Pressure);
      ENTH = Function6(DB,WB,Pressure);
   }
    else if(InputCombination == 4)
    {
      DB = Input1;
      ENTH = Input2;
      HR = HumRatfn_DB_Enthalpy_Pressure(DB,ENTH,Pressure);
      RH = RelHumidityfn_DB_HumRat_Pressure(DB,HR,Pressure);
      WB = WBTempfn_DB_RH_Pressure(DB,RH,Pressure,1);
      DP = Function4(DB,WB,Pressure);
      SpVOL = Function5(DB,WB,Pressure);
   }
   else
   {
     DB = Input1;   // + KtoC
     WB = Input2;   // + KtoC
     HR = HumRatfn_DB_WB_Pressure(DB,WB,Pressure);
     RH = RelHumidityfn_DB_WB_Pressure(DB,WB,Pressure);
     DP = DewPointTempfn_DB_WB_Pressure(DB,WB,Pressure);
     SpVOL = SpecVolumefn_DB_WB_Pressure(DB,WB,Pressure);
     ENTH = Enthalpyfn_DB_WB_Pressure(DB,WB,Pressure);
   }

    AirProperties[0] = DB;
    AirProperties[1] = WB;
    AirProperties[2] = HR;
    AirProperties[3] = RH;
    AirProperties[4] = DP;
    AirProperties[5] = SpVOL;
    AirProperties[6] = ENTH;

    FreeLibrary(MathRoutinesInstance);

    return AirProperties;
}

double DLL_EXPORT __cdecl Function8(double DBTemperature, double RelHumidity, double Pressure,int LoadLibraryFlag)   //
{
/*
    Input:
    DBTemperature - Dry bulb Temperature [C]
    RelHumidity - Relative Humidity [-]
    Pressure    - Barometric Pressure [kPa]

    Output:
    WBTemperature- Wet bulb Temperature [C]

    Reference:
    ASHRAE Fundamentals (SI) - Chapter 1
*/
  bool Converged;
  bool RHBounded;

  double WBTempHi;
  double WBTempLo;
  double WBTemperature;

  double RHCalc_Lo;

  double Params[2];

  Converged = false;

  WBTempHi = DBTemperature;
  WBTempLo = DBTemperature - 4.0f;

  HINSTANCE MathRoutinesInstance;

  if(LoadLibraryFlag == 0)
  {
    MathRoutinesInstance = LoadLibrary("./MathRoutines.dll");
    BisectionRootFinder = (fp_BisectionRootFinderTYPE) GetProcAddress(MathRoutinesInstance,"BisectionRootFinder");
  }

// Do some calculations here

  if(Converged == true)
    WBTemperature = WBTemperature;
  else
  {
    Params[0] = DBTemperature;
    Params[1] = Pressure;

    WBTemperature = BisectionRootFinder(WBTempLo,WBTempHi,RelHumidity,0.0005,Params,50,RelHumidityfn_WB_Params);
  }

  if(LoadLibrary == 0)
  {
      FreeLibrary(MathRoutinesInstance);
  }

  return WBTemperature;
}
```

As you will notice the said dll references another dll "MathRoutines.dll" to do a calculation. In Function8 I had an if block to load the Mathroutines dll. This is because I will be using the dll in my C# interface program where function8 will be called directly. Since Function 8 uses a function from MathRoutines.dll, I need to load it when called directly.

With this set up the program was having the problems I mentioned in original post. I realized that the freezing has nothing to do with files. Now just as a try while making simple working example, I commented the following lines in Function8:

```
/*
  HINSTANCE MathRoutinesInstance;

  if(LoadLibraryFlag == 0)
  {
    MathRoutinesInstance = LoadLibrary("./MathRoutines.dll");
    BisectionRootFinder = (fp_BisectionRootFinderTYPE) GetProcAddress(MathRoutinesInstance,"BisectionRootFinder");
  }
*/
```

and

```
/*
  if(LoadLibrary == 0)
  {
      FreeLibrary(MathRoutinesInstance);
  }
*/
```

In addition, I had to also comment the FreeLibrary call at the end of Function1. With the above changes the application works fine. I did not include FORTRAN code here since it seems that the problem is something to do with how I load the MatRoutines Library in C++.

I would like to know how the commenting of the lines I showed above made it work. What is the right way to load/unload DLL.

Comment: please show your code, otherwise it is difficult to guess. is your application single-threaded?

Comment: I think a minimum working example is in order here.

Comment: I have added new information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an MSWindows program. I am guessing you have a problem with name mangling. Fortran code compilers add a single underscore to the function name. Sometimes your compiler will also prepend an underscore so your function `BisectionRootFinder` becomes either BisectionRootFinder_ or _BisectionRootFinder_

You should have a look on the output of this command

```
dumpbin /SYMBOLS MathRoutines.dll
```

I used this routine many years ago. Now I don't have MSWindows anymore so please don't trust the command syntax fully, experiment with it.

Comment: This is improbable. If he knows c_f_pointer, he should also know bind(C).

Comment: Thanx @Vladimir. I'd still like to get a glimpse on the flags supplied to the compiler